# How to add Addictive Drums 2 to Studio One?

Tags: daw, vst

Where can I find the Addictive Drums 2.DLL file so I can include this in my DAW. Please help me fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Studio One options and click on **Add** which comes under VST Plug-Ins tab.

[image]

Go to following location=> `%PROGRAMDATA%\XLN Audio\`

[image]

Here you can find Addictive Drums' DLL files according to host bit. Simply you can add the preferred path to the Studio One as I did.

`i.e. C:\ProgramData\XLN Audio\VST64`

Answer (score 0):

Note that VST support is not available with the free version of Studio One (Prime). You need at least Studio One 5 Artist. (previous versions of Studio One Artist required a not-free VST extension)